# Is this a correct sentence. "If I want to do this, so do you."?

Tags: speech

As we say, "If I can do that, so can you". In a similar way can we use the sentence, "If I want to do this, so do you."?

Comment: Your question looks right, and your title looks wrong.

Comment: @YosefBaskin My bad. It means that what I asked is correct?

Comment: Yes, but where would you use the sentence?

Comment: Syntactically, it's no problem. But semantically and pragmatically, it's a mess. How can you know what somebody else wants enough to make it contingent on your own desires, without making that statement into an order?

Comment: I imagine it could be used in the context of an online how-to video and conveys the same thinking as “I want to be able to do X and I assume I’m not the only one.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's grammatically correct, but I think a better phrase might be something like:

> If I want to do this, you should want to do this.

Comment: Or perhaps "If doing this would be good for me, it would be good for you"